# HTML Confine Words in an Area

Tags: html, fonts

I'm creating a menu webpage and I'm using rows to list the items but there is a problem where the names are too long and alter the size of my box (class thumbnail). Here is an example:

puu.sh/iPAuk/655ec1151a.jpg

I want to keep all the boxes uniform in size even if the text is different lines. Thanks!

Here's the code:

puu.sh/iPB4F/34a74381be.png

Comment: Hey, pssst, got any code?

Comment: But how can we copy your code? Project Naptha?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `text-overflow: ellipses` to cut off the text.

```
p {   
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z80ucfoy/)

Answer (score 0):

Make every single menu item a separate div, then set all those divs to have the same height.

Comment: When I do that, if I zoom in the browser over 100% it will make the divs disappear.